# dependency not found in maven pom.xml file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, pom.xml

I'm trying to load some packages into my maven project using pom.xml file but the version tags always show the red color saying the dependency is not found. I tried invalidate & clear caches but it still doesn't work. I know I can manually import jar files into the modules setting yet it bothers me not knowing why this keeps happening.

[image: project/ dependency not found]

This happens to every dependency that I tried to insert in. Does anyone know the solution? I'm using IntelliJ.

Comment: Build on plain command line first... or reload the project in intellij ...

Comment: look at InteliJ logs Help -> Show log

Comment: Does `mvn clean compile` complete successfully in terminal? If so, after this command - try just restarting the IDE and **Reload** action in Maven tool window. Does it help?